# Programming a UIButton as a toggle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

This is how I'm making my UIButton to manage favorites:

```
-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender
    {
    if (favoriteButtonSelected == 0) {

        [sender setSelected:YES];

        favoriteButtonSelected = 1;
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritedItem.png"]];
        [selectedObject setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"Favorite"];

    } else {

        [sender setSelected:NO];

        favoriteButtonSelected = 0;
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite.png"]];
        [selectedObject setValue:@"No" forKey:@"Favorite"];
    }
}
```

And this to set the default state for button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[selectedObject valueForKey:@"Favorite"] isEqual:@"Yes"])  {

        [favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritedItem.png"]];
        [favoriteButton setSelected:YES];
        favoriteButtonSelected = 1;

    } else {

        [favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite.png"]];
        [favoriteButton setSelected:NO];
        favoriteButtonSelected = 0;
    }
    }
```

And my questions are: How to declare favoriteButtonSelected? And how to make the reference to the button (favoriteButton) and favoriteButtonSelected in viewDidLoad?

Comment: declare it as an int in your header?

Comment: Done, but what about the viewDidLoad button reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a UICheckbox solution which is essentially just a toggle of a sort.  You can easily replace the images provided in my source project and have what you're looking for:

https://github.com/Brayden/UICheckbox